# How to scrolldown a Container to some precise coordinate

Tags: java, scroll, codenameone

Simplifying, I have this structure

```
Form {
   tab=Container(BoxLayout.y());
   other stuff
}
```

The Form is not scrollable (and it is not supposed to be), tab is.

At some point I want to redraw the Form to keep it up to date with some new info added, and I do that creating a new one and showing it.

But I want to scroll down the Container *tab* to its predecessor's Y-coordinate.

I can easily save the Y coordinate in a static variable using

```
scrolledToY=tab.getScrollY();
```

But I can't find a way to set it back when I create the new form.

*setScrollY* seems to be protected, and indeed if I try to run the program using it, I get an error

> error: setScrollY(int) has protected access in Component
> tab.setScrollY(scrolledToY);

What is the correct function to use, instead?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollRectToVisible()`.

FYI you can just modify the container and call revalidate to update the UI. This will prevent a nasty refresh problem you might experience. Also check out `InfiniteContainer` which might be what you're really looking for.

Comment: Actually, the design is a bit more complex, and the changes happen in the whole application, so modifying only the container wouldn't cut it.
At the end, anyway, I found more practical to simply extend the Container class and make the setScrollY public (hoping that there was not a stringent reason for making it not public in the first place). It seems to work, without side effects, at least in the simulator, for now (I hope it will stay this way even in the final app). 
Thanks anyway. :)